# Returns “Enumeration yielded no results” in LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have trouble with following linq query:

```
IEnumerable<PRINTER> alreadyexist = db.PRINTER.ToList().Where(c => c.REG_ID.Equals(1) && (c.NAME.Equals(“p3”) || c.IP.Equals(“4”)));
```

It does not return actual result. Instead, it just shows `Enumeration yielded no results`. Only after placing the OR operation, i got this message actually.

Comment: can you put an image that demonstrate the data in your table

Comment: It *does* return the actual result, which is nothing, nothing matches. Whatever it is that *examines* the result is what produces "Enumeration yielded no results".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this message appear when there is no data satisify the constraints of the Where Statement, so double check your database table, to ensure that there will be data satisfy those constraints

any way we can improve the query, or write it in another way like the following

```
IEnumerable<PRINTER> alreadyexist = db.PRINTER.Where(c => c.REG_ID == 1 && (c.NAME == “p3” || c.IP == “4”));
```